# Check if the string "00" is a number and return false in C#

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I need to check if a string is a number and then I need to check the arrange of this number. So I use the TryParse method for it but I need for strings "00" or "01" or similiar get false.
With my code I get true:

```
var isNum = int.TryParse(s, out int n);
```

So I have a trouble with such strings ("00", "01" etc) because I got true but I want to get false

Comment: is this helpful `if (s.StartsWith("0"))`

Comment: what about `015`, is it considered as a valid number or not? or only `00` to `09` are invalid?

Comment: @nika what about 0 ?

Comment: Can the string contain any characters or only numeric?

Answer (score 3):

simply (reverse-) compare the result as a string afterwards:

```
var isNum = int.TryParse(s, out int n);
isNum = n.ToString().Equals(s)
```

This assures in any case (and with the [correct comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-6.0#system-string-equals(system-string-system-string-system-stringcomparison)) in any culture)  that `s` is a true int.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to validate that your string is an integer number not prefixed with 0s:

```cs
var isNumberNotPrefixedWith0 = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(0|[1-9]\d*)$");
```

The full regex explanation is [here](https://regex101.com/r/2OyEZM/1).

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a check  `if (s.StartsWith("0") == false)`. so it will return false for all the strings with leading 0.

so you can use the code.

```
bool isNum = s.StartsWith("0") == false && int.TryParse(s, out int n);
```

Comment: How about single 0?

Comment: @Magnus good point, I have asked OP that what is he expecting for 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var isNum = !s.StartsWith("0") && int.TryParse(s, out int n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make the list complete, here it is using a logical exclusive OR:

```
(((byte)s[0] ^ 0x30) == 0)
```

Here an example:

```
string[] inputs = new string[] {
    "01",
    "00",
    "100",
    "0",
    "1",
    "010"
};

foreach (string s in inputs) {
    if ((s.Length > 1) && (((byte)s[0] ^ 0x30) == 0)) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("invalid input: " + s);
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        int.TryParse(s, out i);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("valid input: " + i.ToString());
    }
}
```

The result:

```
invalid input: 01
invalid input: 00
valid input: 100
valid input: 0
valid input: 1
invalid input: 010
```